# Disallow edit and update after a deadline -- do it in model or controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an education app in which a `submission` cannot be edited and updated when its `assignment`'s deadline has passed. (NB: `submission` belongs_to `assignment`)

I figure I could do a model validation on `submission`

```
# submission.rb
validate :cannot_be_updated_past_deadline, on: :update

def cannot_be_updated_past_deadline
  if updated_at > assignment.deadline
    errors.add(:updated_at, "can't be past deadline")
  end
end
```

Or I can accomplish the same goal in the controller

```
# submissions_controller.rb
before_action :stop_late_edit, only: [:edit, :update]
def stop_late_edit
  sub = Submission.find(params[:id])
  if Time.now > sub.assignment.deadline
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

What is the pros and cons of the two methods?

In addition, if I want to disallow methods based on more complicated conditions (i.e. model validation won't suffice), is `before_action` in controller the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in the **model**. The model is the responsible to represent the information and data. Among other responsibilities with that data, **validation** is one of them.

Right now you might have just this controller which access that data, but hey, who says that your education app won't need an API controller in some months? You don't want to repeat validation there.

I can't give you a cons for putting the validation in the Model. From my point of view and experience, is where it makes sense to validate data that is going to be inserted in the DB (in your case with an update).

However, if you want users to not be able to access particular controller actions based on some conditions (the user is not an admin is a common example), yes, you want to do a `before_action`. Notice that in this case you are not updating the DB, so, validation of the data is not needed here.